# Fetching VM details from multiple tenants

Tags: azure

we are developing an application where any customer can log in using Azure active directory.
We need some way to read user tenant information and then fetch all the VM associated with his subscription.

Comment: Please check this website where you can login with azure ad and it will get all details

Comment: https://overcast.sharegate.com/login

Comment: Please make you question more specific and do not post your product link here. We don't provide a product solution for you.

Comment: Its not my product..but i have given example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can register your application as multi-tenant app so that users in external Azure AD will be able to login your application . For details about  multi-tenant app, pls refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

For fetching VM information in users' Azure subscription , you need to implement a process that letting your user(should with Azure subscription owner role) to grant at least read VMs permission of users' subscription to your multi-tenant app so that your app can get users' VM information you need.

I'll explain the details of the hole processes of your requirement :

**Step1:**

You can just refer to [this doc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) to deploy a multi-site app.If users from other Azure AD(We call it B tenant here)want to use your multi-tenant app , the admin of B tenant should sign up in your app (This process you can see the details [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect#sign-up))

**Step2:**

Once the AD admin finished the sign-up process, your multi-tenant app will appears in "Enterprise applications" of B tenant . You can find it using your multi-tenant app ID : 
[image]
This step is just for checking that if your app have resided customer's tenant successfully .

**Step3**

This step will grant VM related permissions of certain Azure subscription of tenant B to your multi-tenant app. You should let the Azure Subscription Admin(who has the owner role) to grant this permission: 
Go to subscription blade : 
[image]

Add "Virtual machine contributor" role(this is a built-in role,it has all VM management permissions, for than reading permission ) to your multi-tenant app ,you can find your app using its app id :
[image]
Select it and then click "save", this step is finished .

**Step 4**

Trying to get the VM information from certain Azure subscription of B tenant.
This step , I will use REST API to get the VM information you need. 
Get access token from B tenant :

```
Request URL:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<-B tenant name->/oauth2/token

Request header:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Body: 
client_id=<-your multi teant app id->&
client_secret=<-client secret of your multi tenant app->&
grant_type=client_credentials&
resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

You can get an access_token to get the VM infos you need via the REST API below :

```
Request URL:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<-your users' subscription ID->/resourceGroups/<-the resource group you want to query ->/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2018-06-01

Request Header : 
Authorization: Bearer <-access token->
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me : 
[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks kiron for perfect explanation

Comment: Can you please help how we can grant permission to user subscription?

Comment: Hi @Sachan ,I was enjoying my holiday in last 2 days . I have updated the answer , pls go through it. If you have any unclear , pls let me know and if my answer is helpful for you , your marking will be the greatest return for me : )

Comment: Hi sir, i tried all approaches but i am not able to get tenant details & subscription details

Comment: Also as you mentioned in step 3 to provide vm access. We cant do like this as customer will login to our application and using consent we want to read his vm details. We cant ask cuatomer to follow step 3.

Comment: You should provide the details of step3 to your customer and let the customer grant associated permissions to your multi-tenant app manually. AFAK , this is the only way that you can access your customers' Azure subscription . Though you can finish this process using API , but it is not recommanded by MSFT as security reasons .

Answer (score 0):

1. We have configured a multi-tenant AD-APP on **tenant-1**
2. The same AD-APP has contributor permission on VM-1 of **tenant-2**
3. We are trying to list all the VMs of tenant-1 and tenant-2. Is this possible by passing just the tenant-1 on API ? Or, it will just list the VMs of tenant-1 only as we are calling the API with tenant-1 ?