# Not able to fetch subscription details

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a multi tenant azure application. When i am trying to fetch subscription details using azure management api, it is always giving null.

I have followed all the steps except step3 mentioned in this post

[Fetching VM details from multiple tenants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56160578/11185426)

Comment: May I know,  Why u didn't follow step 3 ?

Comment: My application will be useed by end customer. How its possibke to ask for these steps?

Comment: if its not giving you auth error, but gives null - means you are querying wrong scope

Comment: Yes it seems wrong scope

Comment: But unabke to find what else i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems that you are trying to get azure subscription Information.

Try with REST API:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions
```

Note: Refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list). Then click on `Try it` section.

See the screen shot:

[image]

Click on `Try it`. you will prompt to login login with your credential. After that you will be given option for which tenant you want to get subscription. In response you would get your information like below:

[image]

Comment: The user has already given consent ti azure service management api

Comment: Where else we gave to enable it?

Comment: @Sachan I have updated the answer. Please have a look. and let me know if it is working fine.

Comment: This will work if you logged to portal directly.. I have tried same but when come via multi tenant application, the respone comes null

Comment: Did you get for single tenant even?

Comment: Nope ..for none. when i follow the step 3, it works fine. But as i mentioned we want to do it automatically without step 3.

Comment: you can check this site which are following the same process overcast.sharegate.com

Comment: @Sachan You must have to assign role to the requested user other then value would be empty.

Comment: Have you gone through the site i mentioned?. i am also asking the same consents .

Comment: How they come to know about my all tenants and subscription details ?

Comment: Using same API which I have referred to you. You can also know here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get#code-try-0

Comment: So I think the way I have explained is correct. Without role assignment you could not get that information. Hope you understand and accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: My question is , adding the role is manual task . and how we can do at customer end ?  i also explored same api which shared . nothing works.

Comment: yes..after providing role access , i am able to see the details

Comment: So role is mandatory here otherwise any one can get your information who are user but normal uses shouldn't have this permission either and it is not relevant though. Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: Yes i know its required, if we have already given consent to use application service management api ,then why its required. if you go through the sample site , you will understand the actual issue

Comment: I know your concern, when we consented `service management api` it is not seems good that all users should avail it. Only assigned users should.

Comment: @Sachan If all these helpful you could accept my answer. Thank you.